# How do I make kvkbd virtual keyboard appear on the login screen?

Tags: fedora, kde, touch-screen, kdm

I am trying to set up Fedora (KDE desktop) on a PC with a touch screen. I got kvkbd working which I am finding works decently enough that I might be able to use this machine without a keyboard at all, which is the final goal. But for now I have no access to it from the login screen, so I need to use an actual keyboard just for that part.

**How can I configure it to appear at login, before entering the user's desktop?**

I have followed some of the directions in the 'Kvkbd Handbook' in the help menu of the software, including adding lines to /etc/kde/kdm/Xsetup and using the `--loginhelper` parameter. So far, no luck.